# Hats Load on Pages, but don't always go away

Tags: bug, status-completed, winter-bash-2015

I had an interesting problem with hats loading oddly this afternoon:

[image: many hats]

When I changed the hats on a separate tab, the hats loaded in, but never left, which was awkward for all of us.

I was running Safari 9.0.2 (11601.3.9) on Mac OS X El Capitan on [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/66656/44713) with no add ons when the bug occurred.

Comment: You don't happen to remember what page this happened on?

Comment: @balpha I _think_ it was [this one](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/66656/44713), but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: Excellent, that confirms my theory. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There was an issue in the Winter Bash code that could cause old hats to not be removed when they're being replaced with new ones if the page contains elements that look like they may contain avatars but actually don't. This is fixed now.